# How do I use Python's cmd module with context

Tags: python, interpreter, dispatch

I'm trying to use Python's cmd module to interpret the player's commands but I can't get it to work in a that the 'game world' is affected.

From testing, it seems like player.cmdloop() just runs in the scope of the player instance; In the code below, game() gets run as it normally would then gets to the player.cmdloop() at which point player.cmdloop() runs. Once an input is run, cmdloop() ends, it goes back to the top.

I've tried many different approaches so I think it's an issue with my design/implementation due to lack of understanding.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    import cmd 

    who_dict = {}
    class MyConsole(cmd.Cmd):

        def __init__(self):

            cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

        def do_who(self, args):
            game().who()


    class Human(object, MyConsole):
        """The human player
        """
        prompt = ">> "
        def __init__(self, name, health, gold):
            MyConsole.__init__(self)
            self.name = name
            self.health = health
            self.gold = gold

        def do_swing(self, args):
            game().swing()



    class Monster(object):
        """Item Class
        """
        def __init__(self, name, hp):
            self.name = name
            self.hp = hp



    def game():
        global who_dict
        """ Main game function """

        # when game is started.  
        # load the game_state file
        # initialize the console 

        # Sample game_state. Will be loaded from file.

        game_state = {
                    'players'   :   [
                                        Human('Joe', 100, 10),
                                        Human('Frank', 100, 20)
                                    ],



                    'monsters'  :   [
                                        Monster('goblin',1)
                                    ]
                    }     



        for player in game_state['players']:
            who_dict.update({player.name:player})

        def who():
            for name in who_dict.keys():
                print name

        def swing():
            print "You briefly flail your arms like a mad man, attempting to hit something."


        player.cmdloop()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        player = Human('Ben', 100, 10)
        game()
```

Results in:

```
    >> swing
    >>
```

Comment: Human inheriting from a console looks ... suspicious ;0

Comment: It was one of my many attempts to get this working.

Comment: If your class diagram speaks nonsense, then it's very probable that something is very wrong with your design :)

Comment: I agree that it's an issue with my design. I was hoping someone could help me understand where the interpreter should go or how it can be used so that commands are pass between classes?  Right now, I just get another prompt and no errors.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Hopefully someone will have time to elaborate on your snippet, I can't do this right now. If you wanted to solve this problem yourself, I'd suggest starting over, and going by **small** steps. Currently it looks as if you wanted to do all of this at once (or made some big refactoring all over). Forget about all this code, and start with the simplest way to make a console accepting commands and doing nothing. Then add other small things one by one.